# Windows Phone 7 - application cannot launch for debugging

Tags: windows-phone-7, visual-studio-debugging

I create a windows phone 7 application and want to debug it (F5). But when I press F5 than I get the error:

```
The application could not be launched for debugging. 
Ensure that the target device screen is unlocked 
and that the application is installed.
```

I don't know why this failure comes up.

Hope someone has an idea. I use Visual Studio 2010 Premium.

Thanx
newone

Comment: change the debugger from `Windows Phone Device` to `Windows Phone Emulator` You'll find the dropdown at the top.

Comment: have you developer unlocked your phone?

Comment: Yes I have, so you mean register it or not?

Comment: Are you getting this message even from the emulator? "Ensure that the target device screen is unlocked 
and that the application is installed." if not let us know the actual error message if you try emulator.

Answer (score 7):

I was having the same problem. In my case, the files generated from xaml were corrupted. (e.g. MainPage.g.cs). To fix the problem, I had to delete these files and let the system regenerate them.

Steps

1. Close VS2010 and emulator
2. Delete obj and debug folder
3. Open your solution and rebuild

Comment: Thank you for the tip. Following your hint, I rebuilt the app, and it worked.

Comment: Caution with this: since it forces a full re-instally, it also apparently wipes all the app data (or at least the SQL part).

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating any new project or opening any downloaded project then this issue came. Check the value circled to ask the debugger to build and deploy the app.

[image: Click the properties of solutions to get this..]

Hope this may solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

Which Operating System are you debugging this on?
As far as I know, WP7 debugging on an emulator only works on Windows Vista and Windows 7.

If you are using one of the above mentioned OS's, then try the following -:
Go to the properties window of the Solution and navigate to the Configuration settings. Make sure that the Build and Deploy options are checked for the WP7 project.

Comment: I have Windows 7 and I checked the settings and Build/Deploy is checked. That is all ok.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to debug on your device. If this is your intention:

1. See if you have zune installed
2. Connect your device and unlock the screen before deploying.

If you want to debug on the emulator
 change the debugger from `Windows Phone Device` to `Windows Phone Emulator`.

Comment: That is all what I make. But no luck.

Comment: Did you download the sdk available [here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=27570)? It comes with VS2010 Express bundled with it. If nothing else solves your issue, you could do a fresh install with the bundled software.

Comment: At the beginning i had this. but than I have two Visual Studio files. Express and Premium. And I want to use only Premium. But when there is no other way than I have to do this.

Comment: newone? did you end up solving this? I'm in the same position as you. changed from express version to professional and can't get it working as of right now (still looking for a person with similar issue who solved it)